# Spring MongoTemplate query on array subdocument using $filter and $slice

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

My sample document is

```
{
 "projectId":1,
"photoList" : [
        {
            "mobileUrl" : "tempUrl", 
            "category" : "abcd", 
            "selectedByClient" : false
        }, 
        {
            "mobileUrl" : "tempUrl", 
            "category" : "xyz", 
            "selectedByClient" : true
        }, 
         {
            "mobileUrl" : "tempUrl2", 
            "category" : "xyz", 
            "selectedByClient" : true
        }, 
        {
            "mobileUrl" : "tempUrl", 
            "category" : "xyz", 
            "selectedByClient" : false
        }]
}
```

My requirement is to fetch just photoList element based on array subdocument element filter.

e.g. Get photoList where selectedByClient = true and category = "xyz" and count = 1. It should return

```
{"photoList":[{
            "mobileUrl" : "tempUrl", 
            "category" : "xyz", 
            "selectedByClient" : true
        }]}
```

I have tried below code but it throws error

```
MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("projectId").is(id));
        ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project().and(new AggregationExpression() {
            @Override
            public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                DBObject filterExpression = new BasicDBObject();
                filterExpression.put("input", "$photoList");
                filterExpression.put("as", "gallery");
                DBObject categoryCond = null;
                DBObject selectCond = null;
                DBObject cond = null;
                if (!folderName.isEmpty()) {
                    cond = categoryCond = new BasicDBObject("$eq",
                            Arrays.<Object>asList("$$gallery.category", folderName));
                }
                if (selectedByClient) {
                    cond = selectCond = new BasicDBObject("$eq",
                            Arrays.<Object>asList("$$gallery.selectedByClient", true));
                }
                if (categoryCond != null && selectCond != null) {
                    cond = new BasicDBObject("$and", Arrays.<Object>asList(categoryCond, selectCond));
                }
                if (cond == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                filterExpression.put("cond", cond);
                return new BasicDBObject("$filter", filterExpression);
            }
        }).slice(0, 1).as("photoList");
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchStage, projectStage);
        AggregationResults<MyClass> groupResults
            = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,MyClass.class, MyClass.class);
```

Here I am using filter operation with slice which is not working together. It gives error

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property 1@67bde17d found on com.xyz.MyClass!
    org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:262)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:235)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:222)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.getReferenceFor(TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.java:98)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.getReference(TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.java:93)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ProjectionOperation$ProjectionOperationBuilder$OperationProjection.getOperationArguments(ProjectionOperation.java:1411)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ProjectionOperation$ProjectionOperationBuilder$OperationProjection$1.getOperationArguments(ProjectionOperation.java:1479)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ProjectionOperation$ProjectionOperationBuilder$OperationProjection.toDBObject(ProjectionOperation.java:1403)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ProjectionOperation.toDBObject(ProjectionOperation.java:201)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperationRenderer.toDBObject(AggregationOperationRenderer.java:56)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.toDbObject(Aggregation.java:580)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1567)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1502)
```

This code works if I don't use .slice(0, 1) on Aggregation.project().and() method

Does anyone have idea how to use $filter and $slice using spring mongoTemplate?

Note: I am using spring-data-mongodb 1.10.1.RELEASE

Comment: Please don't repost questions. Your output data does not match the same type. Use a generic type and examine the output.

Comment: @NeilLunn My output data matches the MyClass. It just have photoList field. It is working fine if I don't call slice. And calling slice would not change return type.
Issue is in using both filter and slice together using spring mongo template

Comment: It clearly does not match otherwise you would not be getting the error. Change your output class to a generic like `DBObject` or `Document` and if the error persists and is reproducible in this state then you have a different question. But if you persist in reposting a clear duplicate question without paying attention to the remedy then you can only expect it to remain closed.

Comment: @Neil - The problem still persists after changing the output class to DBObject. The problem is in the query generation. I found the below query which is being generated

   { "aggregate" : "__collection__" , "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "projectId" : "14"}} , { "$project" : { "photoList" : { "$slice" : [ "$1@2a3243fa" , 6 , 1]}}}]}

Here in $slice field random string ($1@2a3243fa) is being set.

Is it issue in Spring Mongo?